# License checker crashes after rev update

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lvl

Everything before was perfect... but...
Today something happened to my License checker (without touching a line) and that made my app crash. So I saw there was an update available on the Package Manager for that library and updated (I've updated Eclipse too).
I've also updated the methods in order to make them work with the new update.
It worked for a couple of hours.
After some Eclipse open/close cycle that stop working again (it compiles but crashes):

This is the LicenseCheck.java:

```
package it.android.smartscreenoffpro;

/*
 * @author Nick Eubanks
 * 
 * Copyright (C) 2010 Android Infinity (http://www.androidinfinity.com)
 *
 */
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.vending.licensing.AESObfuscator;
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker;
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseCheckerCallback;
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.ServerManagedPolicy;

/*
 * NOTES ON USING THIS LICENSE FILE IN YOUR APPLICATION: 
 * 1. Define the package
 * of you application above 
 * 2. Be sure your public key is set properly  @BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY
 * 3. Change your SALT using random digits 
 * 4. Under AllowAccess, Add your previously used MainActivity 
 * 5. Add this activity to
 * your manifest and set intent filters to MAIN and LAUNCHER 
 * 6. Remove Intent Filters from previous main activity
 */
public class LicenseCheck extends Activity {
    private class MyLicenseCheckerCallback implements LicenseCheckerCallback {

        public void allow(int reason) {
            if (isFinishing()) {
                // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
                return;
            }
            // Should allow user access.
            startMainActivity();

        }


        public void applicationError(int errorCode) {
            if (isFinishing()) {
                // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
                return;
            }
            // This is a polite way of saying the developer made a mistake
            // while setting up or calling the license checker library.
            // Please examine the error code and fix the error.
            toast("Error: " + errorCode);
            startMainActivity();

        }

        public void dontAllow(int reason) {
            if (isFinishing()) {
                // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
                return;
            }

            // Should not allow access. In most cases, the app should assume
            // the user has access unless it encounters this. If it does,
            // the app should inform the user of their unlicensed ways
            // and then either shut down the app or limit the user to a
            // restricted set of features.
            // In this example, we show a dialog that takes the user to Market.
            showDialog(0);
        }
    }
    private static final String BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY = "It is probably better not to post your key in a place like this.";

    private static final byte[] SALT = new byte[] {-90, 65, 70, -128, -103, -57, 74, -64, 51, 99,
        -95, -5, 100, 97, -35, -113, -14, 32, -64, 89};
    private LicenseChecker mChecker;

    // A handler on the UI thread.

    private LicenseCheckerCallback mLicenseCheckerCallback;

    private void doCheck() {

        mChecker.checkAccess(mLicenseCheckerCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Try to use more data here. ANDROID_ID is a single point of attack.
        String deviceId = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                Secure.ANDROID_ID);

        // Library calls this when it's done.
        mLicenseCheckerCallback = new MyLicenseCheckerCallback();
        // Construct the LicenseChecker with a policy.
        mChecker = new LicenseChecker(this, new ServerManagedPolicy(this,
                new AESObfuscator(SALT, getPackageName(), deviceId)),
                BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY);
        doCheck();

    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        // We have only one dialog.
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Application Not Licensed")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setMessage(
                        "This application is not licensed. Make sure you are connected to Internet. Please purchase it from Android Market")
                .setPositiveButton("Buy App",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                Intent marketIntent = new Intent(
                                        Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                        Uri.parse("http://market.android.com/details?id="
                                                + getPackageName()));
                                startActivity(marketIntent);
                                finish();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Exit",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                finish();
                            }
                        }).create();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mChecker.onDestroy();
    }

    private void startMainActivity() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityPrincipale.class));  //REPLACE MainActivity.class WITH YOUR APPS ORIGINAL LAUNCH ACTIVITY
        finish();
    }

    public void toast(String string) {
        Toast.makeText(this, string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

This is the runtime error:

```
03-16 16:53:59.198: E/AndroidRuntime(29719): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 16:53:59.198: E/AndroidRuntime(29719): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: it.android.smartscreenoffpro.LicenseCheck$MyLicenseCheckerCallback
03-16 16:53:59.198: E/AndroidRuntime(29719):    at it.android.smartscreenoffpro.LicenseCheck.onCreate(LicenseCheck.java:101)
03-16 16:53:59.198: E/AndroidRuntime(29719):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-16 16:53:59.198: E/AndroidRuntime(29719):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-16 16:53:59.198: E/AndroidRuntime(29719):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
03-16 16:53:59.198: E/AndroidRuntime(29719):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
03-16 16:53:59.198: E/AndroidRuntime(29719):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-16 16:53:59.198: E/AndroidRuntime(29719):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
03-16 16:53:59.198: E/AndroidRuntime(29719):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-16 16:53:59.198: E/AndroidRuntime(29719):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-16 16:53:59.198: E/AndroidRuntime(29719):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-16 16:53:59.198: E/AndroidRuntime(29719):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 16:53:59.198: E/AndroidRuntime(29719):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-16 16:53:59.198: E/AndroidRuntime(29719):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-16 16:53:59.198: E/AndroidRuntime(29719):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-16 16:53:59.198: E/AndroidRuntime(29719):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The error being thrown is a classnotfound exception, are you sure you're not missing any lib files from your application?

Comment: It was working great, then I closed Eclipse and stopped working... The compiler doesn't give any error too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Started worked automatically .